# detect stale mongodb elasticsearch river and restart it

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-mongo-river

we are using the mongodb-elasticsearch river plugin [from here](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb)

In certain situations, we have found the river has gone stale.

reasons include

- Restarted Mongodb
- Data type mismatch in fields

And each time we had to manually restart the river and reindex the collection.

Is there any way(tool,best practice, features) to detect a river going stale and restart it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you check out [this](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/river/mongodb/MongoDBRiver.java#L442) line, it looks like the river inserts a timestamp of its latest update. You can compare the most recent timestamp to the current time. If it looks like it's getting old compared to the latest entry in the most active collection in your db, you know there's an issue and you should restart it.

Answer (score 1):

We use something like this in our Ruby application to monitor river latency and send it to statsd. Our monitoring framework then detects when it exceeds a certain value and opens an ops alert

```
j = JSON.parse Manticore.get("http://es_server:9200/_river/mongodb/list").body
j.each do |river|
  es_lag = Time.now - Time.at(river["lastTimestamp"] / 1000)
  stat_gauge "elasticsearch.river_latency.#{river['name']}", es_lag
end
```

You could automate this by issuing an HTTP request like:

```
POST http://es_server:9200/_river/mongodb/{river_name}/{start|stop}
```

To stop/start the river automatically.